# Softlayer cleversafe object storage feature questions

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am evaluating the Softlayer Cleversafe Cloud Object Storage with S3 API  (currently in Open Trial), and I had a few questions about the features.

1) It looks like the object storage account has a limit of 2 credentials.

Can this limit be increased?

2) Looking at the available documentation here -- https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/ -- there does not seem to be any options to be able to generate a pre-signed URL to access/create objects . Is there such an option? If not, will it be available some time in the future?

3) Also, there does not seem to be any options to be able to generate temporary credentials or temporary tokens -- was wondering if an option like this might be available some time in the future.

4) Is the object storage "built-in security for data at rest" automatically enabled for all objects? The available documentation did not specify needing to do anything to enable this, so that is what I'm assuming, but I wanted to check in case I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers.

1.- Currently at this time, we only support 2 credentials per account. This is to allow for key rotation. We'd like to understand your case better, can you emial more details on your usecase to [nicholas.lange@ibm.com](http://nicholas.lange@ibm.com)

2.- You can generate a pre-signed URL. From the CLI, this would be done with:

```
aws —endpoint-url={endpoint} s3 presign s3://{bucket}/{object} [—expires-in {seconds}]
```

3.- Currently at this time, we don't support temporary credentials, but we're going to evaluate the feature further.

4.- Currently all objects are encrypted at REST by default.

Comment: Thanks!  I've verified that I can generate pre-signed URL's for both GET and PUT (using aws node.js and java sdk's, as well as aws cli utility).